# Is it possible to get a decimal output from doing division in Bash?

Tags: bash, floating-point

Basically in Bash, what I'm trying to do is take a input of seconds from a user and find the hours. So basically if the user enter 35 the output should be 0.00972222.

But bash gives me is a zero.

heres the command I have:

```
echo "Enter the seconds you wish to convert to hours: " && read sec && echo " $((sec/3600)) is the amount of hours "
```

Is there a way I can make it so it prints out 0.00972222 if I enter 35.

Thanks!

Comment: **Bash** operated with whole numbers, so you'll  have to use additional tools e.g. **bc** or **awk**: `awk -v sec=$sec 'BEGIN{print sec / 3600 " is the amount of hours"}'`

Comment: Is there a way shorter way, if I use bc? I tried doing bc -l but all I get is "(standard_in) 1: parse error

Comment: Bash does not support rational or floating point numbers, only integers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here try this

```
echo $(echo "35/3600" | bc -l )
```

so your command would look like

```
echo "Enter the seconds you wish to convert to hours: " && read sec && echo " $(echo "$sec/3600" | bc -l ) is the amount of hours "
```

To control the number of significant digits printed, use `scale=N`. For example:

```
$ echo "scale=3; 35/3600" | bc -l 
.009
```

If you also want to have the leading `0` printed (which, weirdly enough, [`bc` won't do easily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8402181/1081936)), you can feed the number to `printf` (which can also round it up/down it for you):

```
$ printf '%.3f\n' $(echo "35/3600" | bc -l)
0.010
$ printf '%.4f\n' $(echo "35/3600" | bc -l)
0.0097
```

Comment: only con about using this is the amount of numbers after the decimals place but it works perfectly

Comment: @shawnedward you can control the decimal points. See edited answer.